# What is the meaning of 国の母?

Tags: translation, words, definitions

I'm attempting to translate parts of my 完全マスター N2 textbook just for the practice, and even though I've already gotten past this section, the meaning of [国]{くに}の[母]{はは} still eludes me. I don't like using Google Translate, and I can't find it in my dictionary.

Also if you could critique my translation, that would be very helpful.

> [国]{くに}の[母]{はは}に[電話]{でんわ}をかけた。[母]{はは}の[声]{こえ}を[聞]{き}いたとたん、[涙]{なみだ}があふれてきた。
>
> "I spoke to my mother over the phone. The second I heard her voice, I started to sob with joy."

Comment: くに #4 [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/62449/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8B/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As shown in @choco's comment above, 「[国]{くに}」 in this context means "one's birthplace", "home province", etc.  It is mostly used when one is staying far away from where one was born and raised ***but is still in the same country/nation***.

When I am in another prefecture, I am sometimes asked 「国はどこ？」,「お国はどちらですか。」, etc. to which I reply 「[名古屋]{なごや}です」.

So, 「国の母」 means "my mother back home".  You yourself are living away from that place/region now, but your mother is still there.

Comment: When you talk about people who are known/apparent Japanese, it means their home provinces, but foreigners, home country, of course.