# Can the declarative of だ、です、etc, be used with adverbs?

Tags: adverbs

Can you use adverbs with declarative clauses? You know, when you complete a clause with い-adjective or a noun and だ、or です particle? Can they take adverbs?

Examples:

彼がとても元気ですね？ (He's quite lively, isn't he?)

彼女がとてもかわいい。 (She's vary cute.)

Are adverbs allowed in these cases? Or are they limited to being used in clauses who's copula is based on a proper verb?

Comment: naruto already mentioned and I add why. 彼がとても元気ですね 彼女がとてもかわいい are meaning "They usually don't look healthy or cute but now/today they do" with ...が〜.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

彼はとても元気です and 彼女はとてもかわいい make perfect sense, as well as とても元気な彼 or とてもかわいい彼女. (Use は instead of が!)

For 'noun + copula' sentences like 彼は学生だ, using とても doesn't make sense. Still, you can use many other adverbs:

> - 彼は**絶対**学生だ。 He is *definitely* a student.
> - 明日は**きっと**雨だ。 It will *certainly* rain tomorrow.
> - 彼女は**ときどき**会社員で、**ときどき**学生だ。 She is *sometimes* an office worker and *sometimes* a student.
> - お父さんは**いつも**会社です。 My father is *always* at work. (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43789/5010))
> - **そろそろ**春だ。 Spring is coming.